# SQL - Como anular junção externa ambígua?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando normalizar um banco de dados para endereços e CEPs. Porém, há situação em que os Correios atribuem, para o mesmo logradouro, um CEP para o lado com números pares e outro para o lado com números ímpares, e outra em que os  logradouros são divididos e, para cada divisão, um CEP para o lado com números pares e outro para o lado com números ímpares. Como há lado nos dois casos, criei uma única tabela, cadastrando "lado par" e "lado ímpar". O problema (junção externa ambígua) apareceu quando tentei ligar os dois tipos de logradouros a essa única tabela Lado, porque provavelmente o banco não sabe qual instrução realizar primeiro, já que as duas necessitam da informação da tabela Lado. Abaixo a figura ilustrativa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, há uma forma de eliminar esse erro de "junção externa ambígua" sem precisar repetir a tabela Lado ?

Valeu.

Comment: O diagrama não me ajudou muito a entender o problema, seria interessante explicá-lo e também acrescentar a consulta SQL que está tentando fazer. Também considere que a ambiguidade pode estar vindo de não especificar na consulta SQL o nome da tabela antes da coluna `idLado`, por exemplo `LogradouroLado.idLado` em vez de só `idLado`.

Answer (score 2):

A ambiguidade pode ser porque na consulta SQL você está usando somente `idLado` em vez de `NomeDaTabela.idLado`. Por exemplo, em vez de...

```
select (...) where idLado = 1
```

...você deveria fazer...

```
select (...) where LogradouroLado.idLado = 1
```

...ou então chamar a tabela por exemplo de `from LogradouroLado as t1` e fazer `t1.idLado`. Pegou a ideia?

Esse `as` é opcional.